# Período de tempo em php

Tags: php

Eu tenho duas dúvidas.

A primeira, eu tenho os horários de abertura e fechamento de um estabelecimento, e tenho a hora atual, como eu faço um algoritmo que calcule se o estabelecimento está aberto ou fechado e retorne um *Boolean 'True'* caso esteja aberto ou *Boolean 'False'* caso esteja fechado.

A segunda, eu quero que um evento expire, eu crio eventos para dias futuros, eu quero que meu programa saiba que ele já aconteceu e pare de exibir.

Meu programa é feito em PHP. Ajudem por favor!

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20622/evento-em-expira%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-data-e-hora-php?rq=1

Comment: Poste algo que você já fez, para podermos iniciar a ajuda, dar uma resposta sem ao menos ver o que já iniciou fica difícil.

Comment: Aqui tem a ferramenta básica para isto, e alguns exemplos de uso. Depois, é só adaptar para o tipo de variável que você está usando para guardar a data e hora: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php . Se isto não resolver, clique em [edit] e acrescente mais detalhes sobre seu problema na pergunta. Sugestão de leitura, fundamental para melhor aproveitamento do Stack Overflow em Portugues: [Tour], [Ask] e [FAQ da Comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverdlow.com/q/699).

Answer (score 0):

Na questão de datas:
Você pode usar a função "now()" do SQL para trabalhar com periodos de tempo.

você faz uma query comparando a data do evento e coloque dentro de um array, assim você tera apenas as datas no periodo de tempo que você quiser.